# Mongoose Error: Schema is not constructor

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

Here my Schema file is given below

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ProblemSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    slug: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    desc: { type: String },
    input: { type: String, required: true },
    output: { type: String, required: true },
    constraints: { type: String },
    statement: { type: String, required: true },
    testcase: [
      {
        input: { type: String },
        output: { type: String },
        sample: { type: Boolean },
        explanation: { type: String },
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Problem", ProblemSchema);
```

When I save data using :

```
const Problem = require("./models/Problem");
const newData = new Problem(data)
await newData.save()
```

I get the "Problem is not a constructor" error. How do I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please import your model like this.

const Problem  = require("./yourschema_file_path");

Not like this.

const { Problem } = require("./yourschema_file_path");

you dont have to destructure while import.

Comment: I did import the model. Still not working.

Comment: @ahnaf Please edit your code and put your import code as well like how you are importing it. Because  when I wrap Problem Variable with brackets then I am getting the same error which you are facing.